# statistical analysis of "stop-and-frisk" data

Tags: generalized-linear-model, proportion, count-data

**Question**: What kinds of statistical methods are available to test whether citizens are disproportionately stopped by police in relation to their race?
In New York City, this was called "stop and frisk", and some data relevant to this question is available at http://www.nyclu.org/content/stop-and-frisk-data

The usual analysis that I have seen is essentially based on comparing those proportions to the proportions of people from census data.  There must be something more substantial, but I can't think what would be appropriate.

**Data:**
Here are some tables for this kind of analysis for the city of Toronto, recording police stops ("carding") by race compared with census percentages,
and the conclusion to be drawn is that blacks are stopped much more often than their representation in the population.

[image: enter imcarding-table]

The available data is much more extensive and records this by year, police district, mode and many other factors. The percentages remain roughly constant over years and are consistent over race by other factors:

[image: carding-by-year]

[image]

I am thinking that some sort of generalized linear model of the counts of carding with population as an offset would give ana analysis of the *rate* of stops, and would allow for controlling for  or estimating other influences.

Comment: What is it that troubles you about comparing the observed proportion to the population proportion? Are you worried that the numbers are inflated by stopping a small number of people over and over? Do you want to control for covariates? (Which?)

Comment: The main thing would be able to control for several factors or covariates simultaneously, rather than looking at such tables one by one